# Получение прав на копирование

Tags: linux

Линуксоиды, доброй ночи, подскажите пожалуйста команду, чтобы получить права на копирования и вставку файла в главной дериктории(home). Заранее благодарен

Comment: Нужны права суперпользователя, если я правильно понимаю...

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo cp index.php /home
```

Соответственно вместо index.php укажите путь до вашего файла.

P.S. так эта команда выглядит под Ubuntu, на других вероятно придется доставлять sudo или делать через su

Comment: Еще вариант. sudo bash и работаете пол рутом. Только аккуратно.

Answer (score 0):

если именно /home/, а не /home/username/, то вам нужны права супер пользователя, можете попробовать набрать su и потом пароль пользователя root, и у вас будут права